# Learning Android Programming Tips (Not asking for books or other common reposts)

Tags: android

I am not asking for book suggestions, but rather a plan of attack for learning Android. I have three books on Android, and even the beginners version is a little confusing. The good part however, is when the book explains the code, I can see the logic in the code, and understand why they are writing what they do; but I would not be able to edit the code to do something slightly different. For example, if the code is to create a button that says "Hello", I cannot write code to make the button Say Hello then open a picture, followed by a website.

I have also tried YouTube, and they have great resources, but again, after the lesson is over, that is it.

The three books that I purchased -"Hello, Android" , "Android Apps for Absolute Beginners" , "Beginning Android Games" - are highly rated on amazon.com, but one thing that they lack is a study plan per se. What do you recommend that I do?

Comment: Practice. Write your own stuff, small and step by step. Start from hello world, go to a button that shows a toast, then maybe a small calculator *(if that's too hard get a good understanding of java first)*. I said it in a similar question a few days ago: You don't expect that you can play guitar perfectly after reading a book about it. Why do you think that reading a book about programming gives you this ability instantly. You have to practice. :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I agree, I am completely hands on myself, but this is so overwhelming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i give you my learn plan, and hope it can help you:

1.read the developer guide by google: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html, from `Actitity` to `Services`, to `UI interface`, etc... Not all post you need read, you can read some parts of them, will give you the global grasp

2.when you have a clear understanding of android platform and develop, you can read the book you purchased, like `Hello Android`, read content one chapter by one chapter, the most important is you must write the code when read the book

3.and then, if you want to develop the game, you can try read `Beginning Android Game` or `Android Game Pro`

4.you can read the api demo, it's good demo and some api good teacher, and http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html it's a good choice

5.right now, you can make some apps whatever you like, make you learning using in the actually project

at last, the best way to learn is the write the code.

Comment: Thanks to you and @David for suggesting the Dev guide, I think it gives a MUCH better overview than the book. I am only a few sections in, and I am comprehending the framework better.

Answer (score 5):

It's still argumentative, and I think it may be closed soon. Meanwhile, I'll try to help because it's the best question someone in your position can ask. This is what I'd do (in fact, what I did):

1. Read Lars Vogel tutorial. It seems to be offline now, but I'm sure you can find. It's a good tutorial, and it helped be *way back* then. There may be better ones today. I didn't check it for a long time now.
2. Read Android Dev Guide, *Android Basics* and then *Framework Topics*, at least up to the manifest explanation. Don't mind if you can't know exactly... you'll end with a good overview and familiar concepts in your mind.
3. Get to know the Views and UI elements. Learn to program the basics of each. Experiment with tutorials and samples. There is an old but good tutorial on [mobiforge](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views) (parts 1--4). It helped me.
4. Search Google code for open source Android apps and code. Study and use them to recreate other stuff.
5. Then, buy at least one of the books of Mark Murphy (CommonsWare here on stackoverflow). There is a print copy of his advanced guide, but there is a subscription based system, too.

This line of flow depends. If you like to dive into full theory (probably better in an didactic view), start with the guide and the books first. But your call, whatever suits your learning better.

Meanwhile, wait for your answer to be closed, I think. :-)

Comment: Thanks David, I think I will focus on one area each day and build on it instead of reading the book and following along. The mobiforge  site looks very useful, I will start with that.

Comment: You're welcome. May you learn and code a great app for the Market! Good luck.