# Porting a simple free iOS app to Android

Tags: android, ios, porting

I'm curious about efficient strategies for porting simple iOS apps to Android. In this case "simple" means an app with one full-screen `UITableViewController` that's populated with an XML file downloaded from a server. The XML file will be identical for both iOS and Android apps.

I have zero experience with Android development. So I've considered various approaches:

- Invest time and resources into learning Android developement
- Hire a free-lancer to port the app
- Just make a crappy Android port myself w/o investing much time and resources

These approaches have upsides and downsides:

- Learning Android development is a decent investment and will most likely pay off in the future.
- Dealing with device fragmentation isn't something I want to invest too much into since I don't want to be an Android specialist.
- A decent free-lancer could have a grip on the fragmentation issue. However that route could make the app harder to maintain. I won't know the codebase. If that same free-lancer isn't available to make updates then I might have to pay another person to get up-to-speed on the codebase.
- Quickly creating a version of the app for a single handset that I purchase would work for that device. However I'm not sure if any one device covers a majority of the market.
- The app is free hence running perfectly on the majority of devices isn't a huge issue for me. If enough users complain I can fix problems on specific devices.

**In this situation what are some strategies for efficiently porting a simple iOS app to Android?**

Comment: There are many questions about porting iOS apps to Android (the "Related" menu on the right side has plenty), and there are some questions involving Android learning strategies (including book suggestions). I remember [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9695245/489607). Of course, we shouldn't be asking for *opinions* on how to develop/port for Android.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not asking for opinions. Just for some guidance from people with experience. I think the related questions will be useful.

Comment: In that case, I believe the related questions and the link I posted will do. Good luck.